# How to execute Vim's sort command from a function?

Tags: vim

I would like to write a function to sort Scala imports.

I have already successfully found the beginning and the end of where the imports. Now I just need to do the actual sort.

```
function! SortScalaImport()
  call cursor(1, 1)
  let start = search('^import') "find first line with import
  let end = search('^\(import\|\n\)\@!') "find first non-import line
  let end = end - 1
  execute 'normal '.start.','.end.'sort'
endfunction
```

The last line of the function should do it but does nothing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Vim is a mode-based editor, you also need to consider the modes when scripting it.

`:normal` is for *normal mode* commands, i.e. the short stuff to navigate (`j`, `w`) or change (`x`, `gUU`) text. With `:`, you enter *command-line mode*, where Ex commands (like `:substitute` or your `:sort`) are executed. Normally, you can just put those as-is into your Vimscript function (e.g. `%delete _`), but as you want to put variables (in your case: line numbers) into it, you need to `:execute` it, with everything but the variables `'quoted'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you add `normal` in your execute?

does this work for you?

```
execute start.','.end.' sort'
```